# Loading svmlight style file when there are less features in the train set than in the test set

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I have updated my scikit-learn version to the latest, 0.15.2 (more specifically, I have created a new anaconda environment). It seems that, in this version, a new ValueError has been defined in the method **load_svmlight_files()** in  **sklearn/datasets/svmlight_format.py** (line 238) :

```
elif n_features < n_f:
    raise ValueError("n_features was set to {},"
                     " but input file contains {} features"
                     .format(n_features, n_f))
```

My problem is, I load a model and then, I want to load my test data, so I use the shape of the coef_ attribute of this model when loading my test data (using the "n_features" attribute of the load_svmlight_file() method). But if the model has less features than the test data, then the loading fails. What is the good way to handle this setting ? I'm not sure when this exception has been added but it seems to be absent in the 0.14.1 release. As an additional question, why this exception has been added ?

```
>>> from sklearn.externals import joblib
>>> from sklearn.datasets import load_svmlight_file
>>> clf = joblib.load('mymodel')
>>> print clf.coef_.shape
(11, 9862)
>>> X,y = load_svmlight_file('test_data', n_features=clf.coef_.shape[1] )
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File ".../anaconda/envs/test/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/datasets/svmlight_format.py", line 113, in load_svmlight_file
zero_based, query_id))
File ".../anaconda/envs/test/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/datasets/svmlight_format.py", line 248, in load_svmlight_files
.format(n_features, n_f))
ValueError: n_features was set to 9862, but input file contains 34912 features
```

Comment: The exception has been added because it's usually a bug if the number of features doesn't match, and when it's not, it's impossible for the library to decide what was meant. For the same reason, this question cannot be answered without knowing how the 34912 test features correspond to the 9862 training features.

Comment: @larsmans The names of the features are always the same, that is the feature "1" in the test data is the same as the feature "1" in the model (or training data), or the column indices in the data matrix and the classifier.coef_ one correspond to the same features. But, it could be that we have unseen features in a test set no ? It seems to me that a model just has 0 weight for unknown feature. Have I missed something ?

Comment: If you know that, then you can preprocess the test file yourself. Your assumption that "a model just has 0 weight for unknown features" is invalid for many models, e.g., nearest neighbors (which doesn't have weights and cannot just ignore the additional features). More importantly, having different numbers of features at train and test time is usually a sign of a bug, so in keeping with ["explicit is better than implicit"](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/), scikit-learn catches that bug for you.

Comment: I just wonder why I have a "core dumped" crash when I load test data with more features than the train rather than an exception that I could catch ?

Comment: That's a bug, obviously. Is that 0.14.1 or 0.15.2? There were circumstances in which `load_svmlight_file` would dump core in 0.14, but they were fixed.

Comment: Ok, my fault, it was sklearn 13. I have not this problem with 15. But I have the same problem when I try to reshape my test matrix using the constructor of csr_matrix, ie with X my csr_matrix for the test file loaded using datasets.load_svmlight_file() : X_reshaped = csr_matrix( (X.data, X.indices, X.indptr), shape=(X.shape[0], n_features_train) ). The matrix has then the good shape, but I have this core dumped crash when I try to use a predict() function on it. Maybe I'm doing something wrong, or maybe the problem does not come from sklearn.